# Реализация копирования файлов

Tags: delphi

Я хотел сделать приложение, чтобы оно "красиво" копировало файл в какую-либо папку. Вот код:

```
unit Copy_Flash;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    cmbCopy: TButton;
    pbCopyProgress: TProgressBar;
    txtFrom: TEdit;
    txtTo: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    procedure cmbCopyClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.cmbCopyClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  progress := pbCopyProgress;
  bCancelCopy := False;
  cmbCopy.Caption := 'Отмена';
  if CopyFileEx(PAnsiChar(txtFrom), PAnsiChar(txtTo), Addr(CopyProgressFunc),
                nil, Addr(bCancelCopy), COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS) = False
  then
    MessageBox(Handle, 'Не получилось!', 'Копирование', MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
end;
function CopyProgressFunc( TotalFileSize: Int64;
                           TotalBytesTransferred: Int64;
                           StreamSize: Int64;
                           StreamBytesTransferred: Int64;
                           dwStreamNumber: DWORD;
                           dwCallbackReason: DWORD;
                           hSourseFile: THandle;
                           hDestinationFile: THandle;
                           lpData: Pointer               ): DWORD; stdcall;
                           begin
                             progress.Position := 100 * TotalBytesTransferred div TotalFileSize;
                             Application.ProcessMessages;
                             CopyProgressFunc := PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
                           end;

end.
```

Что неправильно в этом коде?

P.S. Это я не сам делал, а с самоучителя списал!

Comment: А как это понять "красиво скопировать файл", разве можно и некрасиво скопировать? И, если не тайна, что за самоучитель? Нормальный пример копирования файла на Delphi есть на ИНТУИТ-е.

Comment: Красиво - это в смысле, что бы отображался ход копирования, при закрытии останавливалось копирование, и т.д....

Comment: Самоучитель "Программирование в Delphi. Трюки и эффекты"

Comment: Выбрали бы сначала самоучитель попроще - эта книга уже рассчитана на то, что читатель уже на нормальном (или на среднем) уровне знаком с Delphi, поэтому там и не написано про то, где находится тот или иной компонент. Если Паскаль, хотя бы, на среднем уровне знаете и немного знакомы с Delphi, то можно почитать книгу: Флёнов М. Е. - "Библия Delphi" - там обучение тоже на примерах.

Comment: У меня есть Библия Delphi, просто у меня есть ещё и Трюки и эффекты, и я от туда взял пример.

Answer (score 2):

`function TForm1.CopyProgressFunc` и в `public` её.

Answer (score 1):

Функция `CopyProgressFunc()` не объявлена в секции `interface`.